# Not enough values to unpack in plt.pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am testing plotting a colored mesh based on two arrays. To do this, I first count the values ​​for the first half of the grid, then for the second. I get two arrays and save them to a file. Also I am storing arrays with coordinates.

```
k1s1 = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 11)
k2s1 = np.linspace(-1.0, 0.0, 11)
grid1 = np.zeros([len(k1s), len(k2s)])

for i, k1 in enumerate(k1s1):
    for j, k2 in enumerate(k2s1):
        grid1[i][j] = 1

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/arraytest1.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, grid1)

k2s2 = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)
grid2 = np.zeros([len(k1s1), len(k2s2)])

for i, k1 in enumerate(k1s1):
    for j, k2 in enumerate(k2s2):
        grid2[i][j] = 2

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/arraytest2.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, grid2)

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/k1s1.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, k1s1)
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/k2s1.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, k2s1)
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/k2s2.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, k2s2)
```

Then I extract these arrays from the files and concatenate them.

```
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/arraytest1.txt', 'r') as f:
    grid1 = np.loadtxt(f)
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/arraytest2.txt', 'r') as f:
    grid2 = np.loadtxt(f)
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/k1s1.txt', 'r') as f:
    k1s1n = np.loadtxt(f)
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/k2s1.txt', 'r') as f:
    k2s1n = np.loadtxt(f)
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/k2s2.txt', 'r') as f:
    k2s2n = np.loadtxt(f)

grid3 = np.append(grid1, grid2)

k1s3 = k1s1n
k2s3 = np.append(k2s1n, k2s2n)
```

Then I try to build a color grid using the resulting arrays.

```
plt.pcolormesh(k1s3, k2s3, grid3, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'))
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.colorbar()
```

And on the line

```
plt.pcolormesh(k1s3, k2s3, grid3, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'))
```

an error like this appears:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-76ec1e216ce3> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.pcolormesh(k1s3, k2s3, grid3, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'))
      2 plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
      3 plt.colorbar()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in pcolormesh(alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, shading, antialiased, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2723         *args, alpha=alpha, norm=norm, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin,
   2724         vmax=vmax, shading=shading, antialiased=antialiased,
-> 2725         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2726     sci(__ret)
   2727     return __ret

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1563     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1564         if data is None:
-> 1565             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1566 
   1567         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in pcolormesh(self, alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, shading, antialiased, *args, **kwargs)
   6102         allmatch = (shading == 'gouraud')
   6103 
-> 6104         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
   6105         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   6106         X = X.ravel()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in _pcolorargs(funcname, allmatch, *args)
   5678                 if isinstance(Y, np.ma.core.MaskedArray):
   5679                     Y = Y.data
-> 5680             nrows, ncols = C.shape
   5681         else:
   5682             raise TypeError(

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Though I checked all dimensions of all arrays. Please tell me why this can be and how to fix it?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if some line gives you error then first you should check what you have in variables, you could use standard `print()` for this - ie. `print( k1s3, len(k1s3), type(k1s3) )`  and the same with other variables. Maybe you have wrong value or you need variables with the smae numer elements but they have different number of elements. Or maybe you need to use named arguments in function - to correctly send values - and you should check it in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem and solved it.
When I connected the 2D arrays grid1 and grid2 using the `np.append()` function, one array would be appended to the end of the other, resulting in a large ONE-DIMENSIONAL array.

In order to get one TWO DIMENSIONAL array after concatenation, you need to use `np.concatenate()`.